# Visually monitor area of a window in background

Tags: desktop-recording

Is there a possibility to define a monitor area within/over an arbitrary application window that is in background?

The content of this area either should be displayed somewhere else (always on top). Alternatively a notification should be made on any (pixel) change within the monitored area.

**The monitor area should:**

- be a free selection
- stick to the window, even/especially if it is in background
- ideally be saved and automatically be reapplied, based on the same window title

**The notification should be:**

- positioned independently from the source monitor area
- able to be configured always on top
- able to handle multiple monitor area feeds

**Similar implementations:**

- Compiz window previews in scale plugin
- Cairo dock window previews
- RecordMyDesktop free selection of recording area

**Summary:** The ideal solution should combine the above mentioned implementations in a new way: free selection of a monitor area (from RecordMyDesktop), live monitor of windows in background (from Compiz scale plugin) and completely different target display of monitored content (from Cairo window previews)

**Partially related:**

- [Record multiple areas on single screen at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066190/record-multiple-areas-on-single-screen-at-the-same-time)